# Move column table witchout set type column

Tags: mysql, alert, move

I have database, and I would like move column wutout set column type. I have code to move column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `aaa` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL AFTER `bbb`
```

For detect column type I have this code:

```
SELECT column_type FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'aaa'
```

And when I replace in first code variable type on second code:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `aaa` (SELECT column_type FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'aaa') NOT NULL AFTER `bbb`
```

I have error in PhpMyAdmin:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(SELECT column_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE
>   table_name = `table`' at line 1

Where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have forget the `COLUMN`

it should be like that

```
   ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `aaa` ...
```

Comment: `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT column_type FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name=`table` AND' at line 1`